# How do I get rid of an edge?

Tags: modeling

[image]
How can I get rid of the selected line?

Comment: The question is why do you want to get rid of it. By dissolving that edge you will be left with a large n-gon (a polygon with more than 4 vertices), that will likely create more problems later on.

Comment: The solution depends on WHAT you want to delete so please clarify. If you want to get rid of the vertecies and faces too, that's DELETE. If you don't want an edge there while keeping the vertecies and faces intact, that's DISSOLVE. As cegaton points out, dissolving is not a wise option unless special cases (such as retopology)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the edge without creating a hole : 
In edit mode, Select the edge,  press X then click dissolve edge.

Comment: Note that in case of simple dissolving form of the original mesh won't be preserved and it will be converted into simple quad because geometry supporting that will be removed. To avoid that and create an Ngon use Limited Dissolve; if original faces weren't co-planar this will lead to non-planar Ngon triangulated not as expected when rendering.

Comment: Sorry that does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, press <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Edge* in delete menu.

Comment: Note that this will delete faces which were sharing that edge as well.

Comment: Sorry that does not work mate :(